# Convert {number, Observable<string>} to Observable<number, string>

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to transform an array of objects of type

```
{
  id: number,
  data: Observable<string>
}
```

to an array of objects of type

```
Observable<{id: number, data: string}>
```

only using RxJS operators if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, this should be it:

```
const subject = new Subject<string>();

// Dummy array
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: of("smthing")
  }, {
    id: 2,
    data: of("smthingelse")
  }, {
    id: 3,
    data: subject.asObservable()
  }
]
// Function that maps {id: number, data: Observable<string>} into Observable<{id: number, data: string}>
const mapTo = (array) => array.map(item => item.data.pipe(map(data => ({...item, data}))));

const mappedArray = mapTo(array);
```

Comment: You are my hero!! :)

Comment: Keep on going :)